# Como economizar espaço em log de auditoria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estava a criar um sistema que me forneça dados de meus usuários de acordo com a data que eu solicitar, de X até Y por exemplo. E a única forma que encontrei para isso foi, criar uma tabela dessa forma:

`date` com a data que foi inserido em formato DATE

`name` nome do que foi salvo, por exemplo Browser

`value` o valor inserido, por exemplo, Google Chrome

`ip` com o IP do usuário

Na hora que o usuário entra eu checo se existe uma *row* na data de HOJE com o nome BROWSER se não existir ele insere, se existir ele não faz nada.

Pois bem dessa forma ele ira inserir os *browser* dos usuários que acessaram meu site e depois eu posso selecionar, criar gráficos etc

O problema pra isso seria o espaço, isso não iria ocupar muito espaço? Levando em consideração por exemplo uma media de 5-10 mil visitas por dia, e levando em conta que não vou querer capturar só o *browser*. Como eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: E que tal colocar a estrutura visto que não entendi quais os tipos de campos colocou na sua definição...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta simples para isto é: não dá. E mesmo que ocupe, se você tem essa necessidade você deve fazer por conta própria. Você não tem um problema para resolver, só uma assunto para resolver.

Você tem *log* de acesso ao *site* ligado? Todo *site* costuma ter. Ninguém reclama de falta de espaço para ele. Lá tem todas essas informações que você quer e provavelmente de forma bem mais redundante que ocupará bem mais espaço.

Se falta espaço compre mais. Se não dá para comprar, deixe de fazer o que está ocupando espaço. Não existe milagre.

Claro que existem soluções mirabolantes mas provavelmente não vale a complexidade, além de ser questionável se dará bom resultado, espaço em disco é absurdamente mais barato e sem riscos.

Por algum momento você chegou aceitar a outra resposta, talvez porque achou alguma coisa boa nela mas não totalmente. Talvez você não tenha entendido o que eu quis dizer. Vou tentar deixar mais claro.

A proposta da outra resposta é juntar duas informações que estavam separadas em apenas uma linha. Isto realmente é bom porque elimina algumas repetições. Só que se é para fazer isto então você deve tratar cada acesso como uma linha. Ou seja, sua estrutura tem que ser completamente diferente do que está fazendo. E a forma como está fazendo poderia ser necessário por alguma razão que só você sabe. Ninguém pode dizer o que é melhor sem saber tudo o que está precisando.

O problema dessa resposta é que se é para criar uma linha para cada acesso provavelmente não faz sentido criar um banco de dados para isto, esta linha já existe no arquivo de *log* do servidor HTTP. Basta consultá-la e fazer as estatísticas que quiser. Duplicar esforços sim é desperdiçar espaço. Na verdade, outras pessoas já fizeram isto pra você e existem centenas ou milhares de programas comerciais e livres que geram estatísticas bastante completas.

Comment: Uma coisa que poderia reduzir o espaço seria fazer algum 'cron-job' para eliminar dados antigos, assim, iria manter sempre o mesmo tamanho. Bem, é isso que faço em meu site, há uma tabela com 1.4GB, antes havia 89GB, mas era muitos dados inúteis, antigos. Agora é apagado o que tem mais de 1 semana. Acho que 'é o jeito'.

Comment: Quando eu finalizei o projeto e analisei isso fiquei "só pode estar errado" vejo que uma forma pra isso seria usar um servidor externo só pra isso,

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, de fazer meu sistema gerar relatórios auromaticos e salvá-los e em seguida apagar esses dados inúteis

Comment: @bigown qual seria as informações que o log do http salva?

Comment: @user3163662 todas as que você quiser que ele tenha e que sejam disponíveis em um servidor HTTP. O que você não pode por no *kig*, não pode por em outro lugar.

Comment: Teria como por exemplo saber a duração do cliente na página? tem matérias informativas? desconheço muito esse assunto

Comment: Tem como fazer uma estimativa, mas é bem falho. Pra isso pode tentar, mas também não é garantido fazer o JS ir informando o servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas podem ser alteradas para economizar espaço, mas não é tão simples.

Primeiro, você diz ter `name` e `value`.

**Não seria melhor criar uma coluna para cada value fixo?**

```
   date    |   name    |     value     |      ip
2014/12/27 | BROWSER   | GOOGLE CHROME | 127.0.0.1
2014/12/27 | HTTP_REF  | GOOGLE.COM    | 127.0.0.1
```

Neste caso existiria um duplicação, de date e ip que poderia ser resolvido se fosse:

```
 date      |   browser       |     HTTP_REF     |      ip
2014/12/27 | GOOGLE CHROME   |    GOOGLE.COM    | 127.0.0.1
```

Dessa forma, iria economiza algumas linhas e dados duplicados.

**Porque não usar INT?**

Se o name é inserido por você, porque não usar INT?

```
0 -> BROWSER
1 -> HTTP_REF

   date    | name  |     value     |      ip
2014/12/27 | 0     | GOOGLE CHROME | 127.0.0.1
2014/12/27 | 1     | GOOGLE.COM    | 127.0.0.1
```

**Cron-Job para apagar dados antigos**

Se você salva diariamente, crie um CronJob as 00:00 e com ele faça todas as médias necessárias e apague os dados, num velho `TRUNCATE`. Assim iria converter 10mil linhas em uma contendo todas as médias e dados já calculados.

Comment: Show, nao havia pensado nisso, é pouco mas em grande escala se torna muito.. Tive uma dúvida, Dessa forma que eu apresentei levando em consideraçao a inserçao de valores como COUNTRY (local de onde veio) e BROWSER, teria como criar uma query que me mostre quais os navegadores mais usados em determinado COUNTRY?

Comment: Você pode usar "SELECT Value, count(Value) `Value` FROM `Visitas` WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM table WHERE Name = 'Country' and Value = 'BRAZIL') and Name = 'Browser' GROUP BY Value" Se essa publicação foi útil, marque-a como útil.:)